# Cannot define string enum typescript as string is not assignable

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
enum Cat {
    cat1 = 'cat1',
    cat2 = 'cat2',
    cat3 = 'cat3',
    cat4 = 'cat4',
    cat5 = 'cat5'
}
const category: Cat = 'cat' + cat
```

Why do I get a typescript error for that? `cat` is a number, so `category` is a string. But I want to define some specific string values for this variable.

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Cat'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript cant ensure that `cat` is `1,2,3,4, or 5` since it could also be `someThingElse`. Therefore you have to tell typescript that you are sure its gonna be of type `Cat`

The issue here is that the compiler wont allow `'cat' + someVar` to be used as type `Cat`.

Please be cautious when using this, since you essentially overwrite the compilers error. You really need to make sure that whatever you're doing before will always be a valid cat.

```js
enum Cat {
  cat1 = 'cat1',
  cat2 = 'cat2',
  cat3 = 'cat3',
  cat4 = 'cat4',
  cat5 = 'cat5',
}
const category: Cat = (('cat' + cat) as Cat);
```

```js
enum Cat {
  cat1 = 'cat1',
  cat2 = 'cat2',
  cat3 = 'cat3',
  cat4 = 'cat4',
  cat5 = 'cat5',
}

// this would be of however [Cat.cat1, Cat.cat2 ...] would be a lot safer. 
// I would generally suggest not tot use dynamic enum values like this.
for (const i of [1,2,3,4,5]) {
  const category: Cat = (('cat' + i) as Cat);
}

// the compiler would allow this as well, since you ensure that you know the type is going to be if type Cat
for (const i of ['dog']) {
  const category: Cat = (('cat' + i) as Cat);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand that. For my understanding I have to define the result two times as `Cat`. I am obviously wrong, but why do I have to define the right and the left side both as `Cat`?

Comment: Enum in TS are terrible. It will even accept `const category: Cat = 'dog99' as Cat;` which will work as if the enum never existed at all.

Comment: @PeterB if you access them correctly instead of forcing types it works fine `const category = Cat.dog99` -> `// Property 'dog99' does not exist on type 'typeof Cat'.`

Comment: True, but it is so easy to to do it wrong, which is exactly what a strong-typed language should prevent.

Comment: A good rule is if you have to force a type you're probably undermining the safety...

Comment: @pilchard Definitely however sometimes you won't get around the compiler not understand what you are doing. Thats why you really need to know what you are doing when using casting like this

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want category to be one of Cat, not the enum itself. so

```
const cat = 4;
const category = Cat[`cat${cat}`] // category: Cat.cat4
```

This also gives you type safety if trying to access a number out of range. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgFygbwLACgpagY0QRigF4oByPBfUgGg210QCZiyLGa7sKBmF8xbh0xdEAFj4VRQ+hQCsExLNIYAvhgw4A9iADOSCi1EBuDdr0MEwAOaaATgE8W8BAG0ABhQAkyCircBddXQtXX1EADYWcJNgszDLGwdIkmd3Lx8Iv38oAHocqAAFW00AB2BbBEd+BHDSKAATTWAdKBBNJGAADwBLc20oSrKyQeBNADNYRFIAOiA)

```
enum Cat {
    cat1 = 'cat1',
    cat2 = 'cat2',
    cat3 = 'cat3',
    cat4 = 'cat4',
    cat5 = 'cat5'
}

const cat = 4;
const category = Cat[`cat${cat}`]

const cat6 = 6;
const category6 = Cat[`cat${cat6}`] // Property 'cat6' does not exist on type 'typeof Cat'.
```